# ¿Cómo puedo proteger mis archivos JSON de un posible "borrado"?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Trabajo con NodeJS, mi programa está casi constantemente reescribiendo un archivo JSON en la cual se almacenan puntuaciones de usuarios al escribir (y son más de 100 usuarios registrados en dos archivos). Pero anoche, tuve un problema inesperado, mi programa estaba funcionando correctamente, y de repente, se detuvo porque ambos archivos JSON estaban completamente vacíos, perdiendo toda la información que éstos contenían.

El programa completa un ciclo en la que inicialmente lee el archivo:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

Entonces, el programa hace "sus cositas" (añadir puntuaciones, modificar configuración de usuarios como el color preferido, recibir dinero virtual...).
Y luego esta información es escrita.

```
fs.writeFile('./points.json', JSON.stringify(points), function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

¿Qué podría hacer para solucionar el problema? Todos los elementos dentro del programa han sido probados individualmente y no hay ningún error.

Comment: Has pensado en usar una base de datos?

Comment: Sí, SQLite, pero no sé nada de SQLite para NodeJS... a pesar de que tengo el paquete npm instalado, no me he atrevido a usarlo de momento porque necesito saber cómo se podría "traducir" todo lo que he hecho en JSON (lo puedes ver en mis otras preguntas formuladas)

Comment: Que tal un base de datos NoSql? (como mongodb) Son ideales para almacenar datos estructurados de esta forma (pues almacen en el mismo formato). Si quieres "garantias", necesitaras una base y hacer backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar ese error verifica que los json que vas a sobreescribir no sean vacios, si son vacios no deberias guardarlos ya que eso es un problema para ti.

Al hacer `JSON.parse` estas obteniendo un `array` de tus datos que estan en el archivo. Luego de que tu programa haga sus ***"cositas"*** y antes de escribir en tu archivo simplemente debes verificar

```
if(points.length == 0){
    //NO DEBES SOBREESCRIBIR TU ARCHIVO
}else{
    //PUEDES SOBREESCRIBIR TU ARCHIVO
}
```

**EDICION**

Para evitar el resultado vacio en el `JSON.parse`

```
var lectura = fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8');
if(lectura == ""){
    alert("error");
}else{
     let points = JSON.parse(lectura);
    //Aqui el codigo que deje en mi respuesta
     if(points.length == 0){
//NO DEBES SOBREESCRIBIR TU ARCHIVO
     }else{
//PUEDES SOBREESCRIBIR TU ARCHIVO
     }
}
```

Comment: Uh, no entiendo bien el primer bloque de código ni cómo debo usarlo...

Comment: El primer bloque recibe un objeto json y verifica sus propiedades para ver si son vacias, si no estan vacias es un objeto valido (para ti) pero ahora que veo bien necesitas verificar un arreglo json. Voy a actualizar

Comment: Actualice @AntonioRoman

Comment: He hecho un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh7ocn45/) porque hay un serio problema, el problema es que cuando se queda completamente vacío, el archivo no tiene ni los `{}` que necesita para el parse, y por lo tanto, aparecerá el mismo error que aparece en la consola (F12)

Comment: @AntonioRoman actualice mi respuesta!

Comment: Vale, probando... aunque creo que hay una mejor solución, pero lo pondré en otra pregunta, es sobre `https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options`, la función que debería usar en lugar de `fs.writeFile`, ya que en el segundo, cuando el programa escribe dos veces al mismo tiempo, devuelve un archivo vacío, aunque ese método actúa como una especie de "escudo"

Comment: @AntonioRoman me comentas cualquier cosa, si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda marcarla como correcta, saludos!